# How to format/partition new hdd for Windows?

Tags: 12.04

I have one hdd with Ubuntu 12.04, and now I added another one for windows (because I wanna play Day Z =p).

The problem is that the windows installer says it can't partition the hdd (unknown reason).

So I want to use Ubuntu's disk utility to format/partition the hdd, but I don't know exactly what to do (for example, which filesystem does windows 7 need?). Can you help me on this?

Comment: You added a another one!!! you mean a new hdd?! or just a partition?!

Comment: @maythux a new hdd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had two separate problems:

- This particular disk (western digital caviar blue 1tb) uses a different block size, and the disk utility was adding the wrong offset at the beginning of the partition. So I installed gparted, created the partition with it (I used NTFS by the way), and it worked fine.
- Windows won't install itself unless the target partition is in a disk that is set to boot up first, and it won't tell you why either.

Now I only need to add Windows to grub so I can use both OS.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Chocodeveloper,

you need a partition in FAT - otherwise the Windows-Installer cannot recognize - where to put Windows into.
When you dont want to rebuild completely from new and want to keep the Ubuntu - Installation, then you need a live-CD as tool like "knoppix" - and some knowledge about commands: fdisk, cfdisk, mkdosfs (you can find explanations with e.g. man fdisk - in the shell/terminal).

Answer (score 1):

To use the Ubuntu installation disc:

1. Insert the Ubuntu installation disc into the CD-ROM and boot the PC with it. During the boot-up process, select “**Try Ubuntu without installation**".
2. From the dash, search for **Disk Utility**.
3. Choose the HDD in you want to install windows at and then format choosing NTFS as File system.

   [image: Disk Utility]
4. Now restart your PC and install Windows to the new partition (HDD).

   Also you can use **GParted** to do that.

   You can install GParted by

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gparted
   ```

   For more info about GParted, check its [manual](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual).

Comment: Sidequestion: Are these all actual physical SSDs listed there?

Comment: No its just some mess i did it before

Comment: i change the image for not making confusions for others later

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my inconvenience. Have overseen - that Windows has the spleen always to install and always to boot as first OS on the first partition or harddisk.